# SQL for Using Left join with a condition on adding leading zero

Tags: sql

I have 2 data fields on Zip code
one of them is `4 varchar` but the joined table is excel and the leading zero is trucated.

Am trying to add a condition when am joining to the excel to add a `zero` in `SQL` so that the reference works correctly

**example:**

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Excel].[LocationLoading] ll
        ON bld.SLBBLDG_ZIP  = ll.PostCode
```

i need to add

```
CASE WHEN LEN(LL.PostCode) = 3 THEN CONCAT('0',LL.PostCode) ELSE LL.PostCode END AS LL.PostCode
```

Comment: **-** Tag your `DBMS`.  **-** Add sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please add example data and expected results, as per above. We can't really help you without it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have already shown what expression you want to join on, so just apply it:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Excel].[LocationLoading] ll
        ON bld.SLBBLDG_ZIP = CASE WHEN LEN(LL.PostCode) = 3
                               THEN CONCAT('0', LL.PostCode) 
                               ELSE LL.PostCode
                             END
```